# Remove collapsed effect in NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml

In my `ExploreFragment.java` I have a **NestedScrollView**. I want to remove this 'collapsed' effect that it has:

[image]

I've tried to add this line to the XML `android:overScrollMode="never"` but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with.

```
   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">




            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```